# how I can reposition the cursor if the user enters no data?

Tags: c++

I am writing a console program for a class. I have satisfied the assignment, but I want to clear up what is mostly a cosmetic problem. The program prints a form to the console and places the cursor at a location on the form where the user inputs data. The problem occurs when the user presses the enter key without entering data. The cursor goes to the beginning of the next line. If the user enters data after this, the program functions correctly. I want to know how I can reposition the cursor if the user enters no data.
This is the code that reads one of the values:

```
  void getHousing(HANDLE screen, MonthlyBudget &inputBudget) {
          placeCursor(screen, HOUSING_ROW, ACTUAL_COL);
        cin >> inputBudget.housing;
       while (!validateEntry(screen, inputBudget.housing)) {
        placeCursor(screen, HOUSING_ROW, ACTUAL_COL);
        cout << SEVEN_SPACES << endl;
        placeCursor(screen, HOUSING_ROW, ACTUAL_COL);
        cin >> inputBudget.housing;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check the result of input operation .

```
if(cin>>inputBudget.housing)
 {
          //input ok 
 }
else 
  {
      //input failed 
  }
```

Comment: I will try this but what if input fail ?

Comment: also you can do  , if the user hits enter , the string you would .. will be empty . this you can use to detect and fix situation .